# jupyter notebook downloaded as pdf

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to download my jupyter notebook as pdf. At first, I was reminded that I have to install something, then I go to download page to install pandocs-1.15.2-windows. However, when I tried to download it again, another error message shows up: "nbconvert failed: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb4 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)". How can I fix it? Did I download the wrong package?

Comment: Make sure you've also [installed a complete TeX environment](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-tex), such as [MikTex](https://miktex.org/). That said, the error seems to imply to me that this may be a unicode/ascii conflict.

Answer (score 0):

If you opened the notebook in iPython, it has option for download files to PDF pages.